# SwiftUI LongPressGesture takes too long to recognize when TapGesture also present

Tags: ios, swiftui, gesture, duration, long-press

I would like to recognize a `TapGesture` and `LongPressGesture` on the same item. And it works fine, with the following exception: the `LongPressGesture` alone responds after the duration I specify, which is 0.25 seconds, but when I combine it with the `TapGesture`, it takes at least 1 second—I can't find a way to make it respond more quickly. Here is a demo:

[image]

And here is the code for it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var message = ""

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                message = "TAP"
            }
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25) {
                message = "LONG\nPRESS"
            }
            .overlay(Text(message)
                        .font(.title).bold()
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false))
    }
}
```

Notice that it works fine except for the duration of the LongPress, which is much longer than 0.25 seconds.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To having some multi gesture that fits every ones needs in projects, Apple has nothing offer than normal gesture, mixing them together to reach the wished gesture some times get tricky, here is a salvation, working **without** issue or bug!

*Here a custom **zero issue** gesture called **interactionReader**, we can apply it to any View. for having **LongPressGesture** and **TapGesture** in the **same time**.*

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .interactionReader(longPressSensitivity: 250, tapAction: tapAction, longPressAction: longPressAction, scaleEffect: true)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
        
    }
    
    func tapAction() { print("tap action!") }
    
    func longPressAction() { print("longPress action!") }
    
}
```

---

```
struct InteractionReaderViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    var longPressSensitivity: Int
    var tapAction: () -> Void
    var longPressAction: () -> Void
    var scaleEffect: Bool = true
    
    @State private var isPressing: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var currentDismissId: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now()
    @State private var lastInteractionKind: String = String()
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        let processedContent = content
            .gesture(gesture)
            .onChange(of: isPressing) { newValue in
                
                currentDismissId = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(longPressSensitivity)
                let dismissId: DispatchTime = currentDismissId
                
                if isPressing {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dismissId) {
                        
                        if isPressing { if (dismissId == currentDismissId) { lastInteractionKind = "longPress"; longPressAction() } }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                else {
                    
                    if (lastInteractionKind != "longPress") { lastInteractionKind = "tap"; tapAction() }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(50)) {lastInteractionKind = "none"}
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        return Group {
            
            if scaleEffect { processedContent.scaleEffect(lastInteractionKind == "longPress" ? 1.5: (lastInteractionKind == "tap" ? 0.8 : 1.0 )) }
            else { processedContent }
            
        }

    }
    
    var gesture: some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { _ in if !isPressing { isPressing = true } }
            .onEnded() { _ in isPressing = false }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

```
extension View {
    
    func interactionReader(longPressSensitivity: Int, tapAction: @escaping () -> Void, longPressAction: @escaping () -> Void, scaleEffect: Bool = true) -> some View {
        
        return self.modifier(InteractionReaderViewModifier(longPressSensitivity: longPressSensitivity, tapAction: tapAction, longPressAction: longPressAction, scaleEffect: scaleEffect))
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @swiftPunk! The solution you give almost works. Unfortunately approx 20% of the time that I LongPress, it is registered as a LongPress followed by a Tap. Also, at the risk of "moving the goalposts", my original task requires both single-tap and double-tap in addition to LongPress. Adding the double-tap in my code is simple (2 .onTapGesture modifiers in place of 1) and the issue is the same: it works as intended except for the duration of the LongPress. So I didn't mention the double-tap, to keep my example simple. The 2 kinds of taps would seem to complicate your solution, no?

Comment: with gestures, that is what we can get with Apple build in, otherwise you start deep dive in it and making a custom gesture as you wished, so in this answer was focus on making both working alone together for more special salvation I would ask you kindly to make another question and also given the code that create the issue. thanks

Comment: If I can find a solution to the problem I posted that works consistently, I'll see whether it also works for multiple taps—if not, perhaps I'll make a separate post, like you say. For now, it will be a step forward to have a solution for this problem. (I don't expect to solve the more difficult one until I've solved this easier one.) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Found this old question, and since I just had to do something similar, I thought I'd share. I ended up with this code, which seems to work pretty well as long as it's not attached to a Button (which absorbs some of the gestures). Add the below code to an Image or a Circle or whatnot, and it will detect a tap immediately, or a long press after 0.25 seconds. (Note this will only detect one or the other, not both.)

```
      .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
        print("Tap Gesture. \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
      }
      .simultaneousGesture(
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25)
          .onEnded() { value in
            print("LongPressGesture started. \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
          }
          .sequenced(before:TapGesture(count: 1)
            .onEnded {
              print("LongPressGesture ended. \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
            }))
```

I think the source of your problem before was that the tap gesture had to "fall through" to the long press gesture, which took a little time. This one starts both simultaneously, but only one succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The LongPressGesture has another completion that can execute an action when a user first touches down.. and again at the minimum duration. Could something like this work?

```
struct LongTapTest: View {
    @State var message = ""

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25, maximumDistance: 50, pressing: { (isPressing) in
            if isPressing {
                // called on touch down
            } else {
                // called on touch up
                message = "TAP"
            }
        }, perform: {
            message = "LONG\nPRESS"
        })
            .overlay(Text(message)
                        .font(.title).bold()
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @nicksarno. It seems to me that that would fire once on initialization of the tap/press and then again when/if the press lasts 0.25 seconds. It's a good line to pursue, but doesn't solve the problem; what would be needed is need is for the first to register that a tap/press event has occurred, and then to decide whether it is a tap or a longPress depending on when the press ends. If it's less than 0.25sec after it begins then it's a tap; otherwise it's a longPress. In fact, that gives me an idea for a solution which I'll post shortly. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton I edited my answer to what I think might work for you. The isPressing is called twice, once when user first touches down and again when user lifts the finger up. You could make the logic for "TAP" execute when the finger lifts up (when isPressing is false).

Comment: Ah, that's terrific - I never noticed the pressing closure. With the change that you made, that works great. Thanks, @nicksarno!

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark as correct answer if you agree :)

Comment: Of course, Nick. Just wanted to actually test it first to make sure I wasn't missing something! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I tested it and this doesn't quite work either. On a successful longpress detection both the pressing and perform closures fire. Can be fixed by adding a State variable, though.

Comment: Yea sometime I add a 0.1 second delay on the touch up event to first check if the final action was called.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't beautiful, but it works fine. It logs the beginning of each tap/press and if it ends before 0.25 seconds it considers it a `TapGesture`, otherwise it considers it a `LongPressGesture`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pressInProgress = false
    @State var gestureEnded = false
    @State var workItem: DispatchWorkItem? = nil
    @State var message = ""

    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(Text(message)
                         .font(.title).bold()
                         .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                         .allowsHitTesting(false))
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged { _ in
                        guard !pressInProgress else { return }
                        pressInProgress = true
                        workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                            message = "LONG\nPRESSED"
                            gestureEnded = true
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: workItem!)
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    pressInProgress = false
                    workItem?.cancel()
                    guard !gestureEnded else { // moot if we're past 0.25 seconds so ignore
                        gestureEnded = false
                        return
                    }
                    message = "TAPPED"
                    gestureEnded = false
                }
        )
    }
}
```

If anyone can think of a solution that actually uses `LongPressGesture` and `TapGesture` I'd much prefer that!

Comment: you said **If anyone can think of a solution that actually uses LongPressGesture and TapGesture I'd much prefer that!**, in the fact all of them came from DragGesture, apple made that simple TapGesture from DragGesture, it seems crazy, but that is what it is. and when you mix them together it make issue, remember I told you we should work on custom gesture, in my answer for your question, I made a new gesture basically. that is why it works as we wanted. And I named that Gesture **interactionReader**, you can apply **interactionReader** to any View, it would work for tap/LongPressGesture

Comment: Thank you for your solution above, swiftPunk - much appreciated! To be clear, what I'm looking for isn't a custom gesture. Rather, it's an implementation of standard Apple gestures such that looking for multiple ones isn't buggy. In general, Apple's gestures are composable, and composing these works fine as long as LongPressGesture's parameter is 1 second or more… but it doesn't work to spec if LongPressGesture is given a shorter duration.

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed by the delay. There are definitely answers that work for the given question. However, I had an issue as my views were also within ScrollView (or UITableView), so using `simultaneousGesture` wasn't an option as I lost the ability to scroll the view.

But building on @nicksarno answer, I created a custom modifier and leveraged the `onPressingChanged` closure with the custom delay. This way I can trigger the long press action sooner than the native `perform:` closure is called. Also with this approach, you can add visual feedback (in my case – scale the view on long press). Curious to hear your thoughts.

The usage is simple, just replace onLongPress with the custom modifier:

```
Circle()
    .fill(Color.yellow)
    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
        message = "TAP"
    }
    .onScalingLongPress {
        message = "LONG\nPRESS"
    }
```

The implementation:

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func onScalingLongPress(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(ScalingLongPressModifier(action: action))
    }
}

struct ScalingLongPressModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var longPressTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    @State private var shouldScale: Bool = false
    var scaleWhenPressed: Double = 0.975
    var action: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .scaleEffect(shouldScale ? scaleWhenPressed : 1.0)
            .onLongPressGesture(
                minimumDuration: 0.2,
                maximumDistance: 50,
                perform: {
                    // do nothing
                },
                onPressingChanged: { isPressing in
                    handlePressingChange(isPressing: isPressing)
                })
    }
    
    @MainActor
    private func handlePressingChange(isPressing: Bool) {
        if isPressing {
            longPressTask = Task {
                // Wait and scale the view
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200_000_000)
                
                guard !Task.isCancelled else {
                    return
                }
                
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    shouldScale = true
                }
                
                // Wait and trigger the action
                try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200_000_000)
                
                guard !Task.isCancelled else {
                    return
                }
                
                action()
            }
        } else {
            longPressTask?.cancel()
            longPressTask = nil
            
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                shouldScale = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```